# Safari playing a youtube video in the background

Tags: safari, audio, video, youtube

I start Safari, and after a few seconds, I hear what seems to be the sound from a video. (Sounds like a british guy playing minecraft) There are no windows or tabs open to YouTube or any other video site. The sound keeps playing as long as Safari is open. Closing tabs, clearing cache, clearing history all have no effect. The sound only stops when I exit Safari. When I start Safari again, the sound starts again from the beginning.

What is going on? How can Safari play a video if no tab/window is showing a video/video site?

Edit: And how do I make it stop?

Comment: How about your homepage, or the default page that opens whenever you open Safari? Some ads are able to play video on web pages.

Comment: The homepage is a blank page with a search box deal. The sound will start playing on that. And it sounds like some people playing Minecraft, not any kind of ad.

Comment: What does a British guy playing Minecraft's calle sounds like? Does it sound scary? 

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this solution from [Apple's own forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/13250503#13250503) (be sure to back-up your Bookmarks first):

> Open a Finder window. Select your Home folder in the Sidebar on the
>   left. Now open the Library folder then the Safari folder.
>
> Move the `LastSession.plist` and the `Downloads.plist` files from the
>   Safari folder to the Trash.
>
> Restart your Mac.

It also could be an extension messing up with Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same right now....

I found out that clicking on some Youtube link from a Google result search page, will load the Youtube page and start the playback.

Clicking the "Back" button (or swiping right with 2 fingers) will come back to the Google page; but the audio will continue the playback.

That's such weird bug and I am wondering how that has not been fixed since 2016.

However, you just need to find out which tab has a history with a "Next" page and try to click the "Next" button (or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>). One of the tabs should reveal (and reload) the Youtube page that was playing in the background.

You can just close the tab; or, as a confirmation of the issue, go back to the previous page (not tab ☝), swiping right or clicking the "Back" button, and notice how the playback will be keeping playing.

Curious enough, if you go to the previous page via <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> the tab will not present the issue...

...Apple magic.